# Searching a powershell array containing active directory users

Tags: arrays, powershell, active-directory

I'm having an issue trying to find the index number of an item in an array that contains Active directory users.
I create the array as follows:

```
$outarray = @()  
$outarray = get-aduser -Filter * -Properties LastLogon | select "Name","SAMAccountName","LastLogon" | sort samaccountname
```

Now i have the users in an array, and i can prove it using standard variable queries

```
$outarray[0]  
$outarray[1]
```

Returns exactly what i expect.

BUT

I completely fail to search for the index of a `name` or `SAMAccountName` in the array, as they are properties of the array.

```
$index = [array]::IndexOf($outarray.samaccountname, "testuser")
```

returns -1 (not found) or 0 only if `testuser` is the FIRST user in the array.
I cannot find any other user index in the array.

My goal after getting the index is to use it to update the property for lastlogon.  This works if i do it manually
e.g.

```
$outarray[123].lastlogon = 12345678
```

The only way i can make this work is to manually build the array initially, one entry at a time instead of filling directly

```
foreach ($user in $outArray) 
    {
        $myobj = @()
        $myobj = "" | Select "Name","SAMAccountName","LastLogon"

        #fill the object
        $myobj.Name = $user.name
        $myobj.SAMAccountName = $user.samaccountname 
        $myobj.LastLogon = $user.LastLogon

        #Add the object to the array
        $userarray += $myobj
    }
$userarray[[array]::IndexOf($userarray.samaccountname, "testuser")].LastLogon = 12345678
```

Then the search works.  I assume this has to do with property types, but im completely out my depth by this stage.

Thanks in advance for any help, I'm no expert on powershell arrays, they confuse me! :)

Comment: Hmm..what version of PS are you on? Your original set of commands returns expected values for PS3 and PS4.

Comment: have you thought about just using a for-loop and then use the counter variable as index?

Comment: also i agree with Raf, your code works fine on my machine

Comment: Im using PS4 on Win8.1 - I spent almost the whole day friday trying to make it work before posting here.  I agree with you that a test i've just done did indeed return the correct index, and i have no idea why it wasn't working on friday!!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking at this the wrong way. Instead of finding the index of a specific item and then access that item by its index you could do it the PoSh way by filtering the array for the item you want to update, like this:

```
$userarray | ? {
  $_.SamAccountName -eq 'testuser'
} | % {
  $_.LastLogon = 12345678
}
```

or like this:

```
$acct = $userarray | ? { $_.SamAccountName -eq 'testuser' } | select -First 1
$acct.LastLogon = 12345678
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional way of looking at the problem. Most helpful.